# get input value in react failed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Tried to get input's value when user click search but failed.

```
var Login = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {name: ''};
  },
  handleSearch(){
    alert(this.state.name); // doesn't work?
  },
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  },
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" onChange="{this.handleChange}" value=""/><button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
    </div>;
  }
})
```

is there any more straight forward to get the value of input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal issue is that you have quotes around your `onChange`:

```
onChange="{this.handleChange}"
```

it shouldn't have them, that's setting it to a *string* value. Just:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

(as you did with `onClick` on the button).

You'll also need to set `value` to `this.state.name`:

```js
var Login = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {name: ''};
  },
  handleSearch(){
    console.log("name is", this.state.name);
  },
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  },
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} /><button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Login />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: How does that relate to *this* question?

Comment: it doesn't but can you please take a look? :D

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: I'm afraid not. I don't use CodePen, and I don't (directly) use RequireJS, so I wouldn't be much help.